# ConstraintLayout View Gone Keeping Space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have below Constraint Layout for my recycler view. I am hiding and showing this based on Database value from my recyclerview Adapter.Its working but problem is after view gone it is still keeping the occupied space. Below is my xml file

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/books_layout" // show-hide based on this id 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgAvator"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgAvator"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDriverNme" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvD"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#050505"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgAvator"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#FF9800"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#050505"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvTk"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvRatings" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvReg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/strike_through"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#707676"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvBidAmt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am show/hiding with below code from my databind

```
 if (status.equals("1")) {
    books_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
 else{
    books_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```

Below is my current view which demonstrates the occupied space in the middle after view gone.I have no idea how to resolve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to delete the item, you could also set the item's height to 0. Also, you don't need the id. You can just directly call `itemView`. `itemView` is the inflated view of that layout which you inflated in `onCreateViewHolder`.

How to set height to 0:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = itemView.getLayoutParams();
 if (status.equals("1")) {
    params.height = 0;
    itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
 }
 else{
    params.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
    itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Layout working correct.**

your problem is your recycle view **items**.it's item occupied space.

if you want to remove occupied space in recycle view . you have to **delete** recycle view item.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong ,You used this layout in any adapter.It means Listview or recyclerview used in you program , If this is right then you hide your **itemView** .Like this holder.itemView.setVisibily() inside bindView().